# ¿Por qué me sale error al mostrar los archivos guardados en node.js?

Tags: nodejs, aplicación-web, backend

Tengo este problema ya de hace 2 días pero no e entendido el porqué del error.
Aquí les dejo una captura del error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no se como arreglarlo. Aquí el código de mi vista en Jade.

```
extends ../layout.jade
block content  
    div(class="container-fluid")  
        div(class="contenido")  
            each Musicas in musics  
                h1= Musicas.name  
                img(src="/#{ Musicas.cover }", alt="")  
                audio(src="/#{ Musicas.audio }", controls)
```

Aquí el layout al que llama el código anterior.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
html(lang="en")
    head
        meta(charset="UTF-8")
        meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
        meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="ie=edge")
        title Nuclear Originals
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/bootstrap.min.css")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/main.css")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/animate.css")
    body
        block content
```

Los datos de los url de los archivos ya los tengo guardados en mongoDB.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Por favor ayudenme y si necesitan mas parte de código avisenme para que ponga mas aver si ayuda.
Gracias.

Comment: Cuál es la ruta completa que está pidiendo el navegador? No será problema de usar backslash en vez de slash? Prueba pinchando con el botón derecho sobre la petición que te da 404 y abriéndola en otra pestaña para entender dónde la está buscando

Comment: Ok, deja lo pruebo

Comment: Pues lo esta buscando en esta dirrecion,
http://localhost:3000/uploads/a9550ef1bdc9895e47e4dbdd265d1638.jpg
y me manda el error de:
Cannot GET /uploads/a9550ef1bdc9895e47e4dbdd265d1638.jpg

Comment: Ya se porque es porque no esta en la carpeta de public para lo de cosas estaticas en express pero con eso tengo otro error asi que seria fiable mover los archivos subidos a una carpeta en public @amenadiel

Comment: Puedes tener más de una carpeta pública en express. `app.use('/uploads',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));`

Comment: Ooh gracias deja lo intento

Comment: Si me sirvio muchas gracias.
Quisiera darte una manita arriba pero no se puede en comentarios jeje.

Comment: Voy a crear una respuesta para que esta pregunta le sirva a otros que usen express con más de un directorio estático.

Comment: Sale y agradesco tu ayuda Gracias ^-^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como nos pusiste en los comentarios, los archivos que no puede traerse desde el navegador tienen la forma

```
http://localhost:3000/uploads/a9550ef1bdc9895e47e4dbdd265d1638.jpg
```

Si usaste un generador de express o te adaptaste al layout común, probablemente tu carpeta de estáticos sea `public`. Vale decir, en alguna parte de tu script principal dice

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Como `uploads` no existe dentro de tu carpeta `public` sino que está paralela a ésta, en la raíz del proyecto, no puedes acceder a esos archivos desde el browser.

Sin embargo, es posible montar más carpetas usando `express.static`. En tu caso:

```
app.use('/uploads',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));
```

Haría que tu carpeta `uploads`  fuera accesible desde `http://localhost:3000/uploads`.

**Nota al margen para los usuarios de express:** esto sirve también para tratar distinto los archivos de cada carpeta de estáticos. Por ejemplo, mientras estoy diagramando, mis archivos `js` y `css` van a cambiar mucho, pero las tipografías e imágenes probablemente no. Entonces puedes hacer:

```
app.use('/img', express.static(__dirname + '/public/img', {
  maxAge: '12h'
}));
app.use('/font', express.static(__dirname + '/public/font', {
  maxAge: '12h'
}));
```

Lo cual implica que, aunque `/img` y  `/font` ya eran visibles por la primera declaración de `express.static` tú puedes usar esta facultad de añadir y sobreescribir rutas estáticas por ejemplo para modificar tiempos de expiración, E-Tag y otros en algunos subdirectorios selectivamente.

Comment: aunque en el primera estatic de express no use esto. app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); sino que use esto para declarar el public.  app.use(express.static('public'));

Comment: Es lo mismo, sólo me aseguré de usar path para entregar rutas absolutas. Viejas costumbres

Comment: Jaja ok ^-^, aun asi muchas gracias.